# How to change the link of tomcat project index page?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I created a many tomcat servers on eclipse, and I add ressources to each of them.

The problem is that the URL to acced to a page is :

```
http://localhost:8080/project1
```

And the URL for an other one is

```
http://localhost:8888/project2-TRUNK
```

I don't know how it came and what to do to make the 2nd link like the 1st one

```
http://localhost:8888/project2
```

Thank you in advance.

P.S: I use maven for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found 2 ways to do it.

I. Double click on the server -> Click on Modules (Overview by default) -> Chose the server to edit and change the context.

II. Right click on the project -> Propreties -> Web Project Setting. And change the context.